# Were there attempts at coup d'état against Nicholas II of Russia?

Tags: russia, coup

Richard Pipes in [The Russian Revolution](https://www.amazon.fr/Russian-Revolution-Richard-Pipes/dp/0679736603) mentions that [Empress Alexandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Feodorovna_(Alix_of_Hesse)) disliked [Grand Duke Nikolas Nikolaevich](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Duke_Nicholas_Nikolaevich_of_Russia_(1856%E2%80%931929)) (First commander of the Russian forces in WW1), because she suspected him of designs for the throne. The question is: **are there any documented attempts at coup d'état during the reign of Nicholas II?**

I mean specifically the attempts at replacing him by another member of the royal family or perhaps another high-ranking noble family, rather than overthrowing the monarchy, instigation for revolution or assassination attempts, like the one that killed Alexander II. Let us also specifically exclude Nicholas II's final [abdication in favor of his brother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdication_of_Nicholas_II).

More generally: coup d'état used to be commonplace in Russia from the times of Peter the Great till the reign of Alexander I, but somehow came out of fashion in the XIX-th century (if we do not count the [Decembrist revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decembrist_revolt), which attempted to put on the Throne [Konstanine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Duke_Konstantin_Pavlovich_of_Russia), against his own wishes.) Were there particular reasons for this: a succession of particularly capable Czars? Social and political realities making the job too unattractive?

**Remarks and background**
Part of the period mentioned in the last paragraph are sometimes referred to as [*The Era of Palace Coups*](https://golden.com/wiki/The_Era_of_Palace_Coups-VKE884D):

> A period of Russian history between the reign of Peter the Great (May 7, 1682 – February 8, 1725) and Catherine the Great (July 9, 1762 - November 17, 1796) defined by rulers overthrowing each other from the throne with the help of elite palace guard. It is said to be one of the most difficult periods for the Russian throne.

This succession of rulers is sometimes attributed to the lax succession law introduced by [Peter I (Peter the Great)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_the_Great), which opened access to the throne to nearly anyone (notably his last wife Catherine, who was possibly not even of a noble origin, and later Catherine II, who was not a Romanov by birth, but only through her marriage.) This was supposedly corrected by Paul I introducing well-defined succession rules.

However, the sequence of the palace coups extends beyond the indicated period: Peter I himself came to power via a series of coups (first including him into sharing power with his older brother Ivan V, and later possibly aborting a coup against himself by [his sister-regent Sophia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophia_Alekseyevna_of_Russia#Downfall).) Paul I was also overthrown in a palace coup in 1801, which put on the throne his son Alexander I.

Comment: AFAIK the Czar was the target of several assassination attempts by anarchists, socialists and other revolutionaries. I suspect that not many people were eager to get under the Damocles sword.

Comment: I'm afraid the link points to the wrong Nikolas Nikolaevich. The Wikipedia article for the one who was WWI commander is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Duke_Nicholas_Nikolaevich_of_Russia_(1856%E2%80%931929)

Comment: @Pere thanks! Hopefully corrected now (if I didn't mess up the links completely)